# Conditional Probability for a Poisson Distribution: X = 1 | X $\geq$ 1

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Suppose X has a Poisson distribution with a standard deviation of 4. What is the conditional probability that X is exactly 1 given that X $\geq$ 1?

I know that for this problem $\lambda$ is 16 because E(X) = Var(X) = $\lambda$. E(X) is expected value for a poisson and Var(X) is the variance.

How can I solve P(X = 1 | X $\geq$ 1)?

Comment: Are you familiar with Bayes' rule for computing $P(A\vert B)$? Also, note that $Variance = (Standard Deviation)^2$, not the other way around.

Comment: As far as I know Bayes is $P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A) P(A)}{P(B)}$?

Comment: @πr8 Sorry I can go for P(X = 1), which is $16e^{16}$ but I'm lost at P(X $\geq$ 1).

Comment: $P(X=1)=16\cdot e^{\color{red}{-}16}$ and $P(X=0)=e^{-16}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $P(X=1|X\geq 1)=\frac{P(X=1 \cap X\geq 1)}{P(X\geq 1)}=\frac{P(X=1) }{P(X\geq 1)}$ and $P(X\geq 1)=1-P(X=0)$

Comment: I don´t see a simplification with $e^4-1$. First you can expand the fraction by $e^{16}$. This gives $\frac{16}{e^{16}-1}\approx 1.8\cdot 10^{-6}$

Comment: Yes I also realized that when I plugged in the values in R software.